# Apache Karaf - missing dependencies (DataSources as it seems)

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I get the error below when I startup Karaf. A colleague of mine has the exact same features, bundles, etc. but does not get the error. We both use Windows 10 and Karaf 4.0.7.

If fact he just compressed his Karaf folder and gave it to me. So our Karaf installations are identical. Now I am trying to get it working on my machine.

So how could it not work on my local machine?

I don't know Karaf well, so I have no idea how to troubleshoot further. What could be the reason?

Could it be that some jar file in my local Maven repo is missing
(which my co-worker has but I don't have)? I heard this is where Karaf is looking for some components.

```
            data-access (2381)
            ------------------
            Status: Failure
            Blueprint
            10/15/19 4:51 PM
            Exception:
            null
            java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:371)
                    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

            Missing dependencies:
            (&(osgi.unit.name=ybkDS)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager)) (&(osgi.unit.name=ybDS)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory))
```

In fact when I startup Karaf I first get this for a few mins and then I get the error I posted above.

```
            karaf@root()> bundle:diag
            Bundle 53
            ---------
            Status: Installed
            Unsatisfied Requirements:


            data-access (2384)
            ------------------
            Status: GracePeriod
            Blueprint
            10/15/19 6:36 PM
            Missing dependencies:
            (&(osgi.unit.name=ybDS)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)) (&(osgi.unit.name=ybkDS)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))


            website-performance (2385)
            --------------------------
            Status: GracePeriod
            Blueprint
            10/15/19 6:36 PM
            Missing dependencies:
            (&(osgi.unit.name=ybDS)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)) (&(osgi.unit.name=ybkDS)(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManager))
```

What is it looking for that I don't have?

Answer (score 3):

You have a dependency to OSGi services for EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory both with property osgi.unit.name=ybkDS. These services are not coming up. You can first observe this in diag. After 5 minutes the blueprint container gives up to wait for these services and logs an error.

So you have to debug why these services are not coming up. Can you provide more information on how you instantiate the EntityManager?

I guess you are using Apache Aries JPA and maybe ops4j pax-jdbc.
In this case you to check that the DataSource comes up (should also be an OSGi service) and that you have installed the correct jpa impl (like hibernate).

It would also help if you could upload the log (especially everything from aries and pax-jdbc).

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding here... I am not sure I will be able to do all this. As I said I am not familiar with Karaf, OSGI, all this stuff... If you could specifically guide me what to extract and upload here that would be great. Also, my colleague has the same Karaf folder but no issues. So I guess it's something external to Karaf that's causing the issues. Just guessing...

Comment: You can grep the log for "org.ops4j.pax.jdbc".

Comment: OK... btw I started reading the Karaf tutorials on your site :) But I have limited time, in fact I don't need to become Karaf expert... I just need to get it running in order to test some web service in it... Thanks for trying to help, much appreciated. Can I try to setup a chat with you here in SO?

Comment: Yes. If it does not take too long.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if it's possible at all. Btw there's nothing in my log file about org.ops4j.pax.jdbc. All it has is this Timeout error. I will see if I can enable more detailed logging.

Comment: You can tune the log level in etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg. At info level you should see some messages .. if you use pax jdbc at all. How do you configure your datasource?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200957/discussion-between-peter-petrov-and-christian-schneider).